# rails backgroundjob running jobs in parallel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm very happy with By so far, only I have this one issue:

When one process takes 1 or 2 hours to complete, all other jobs in the queue seem to wait for that one job to finish. Worse still is when uploading to a server which time's out regularly.

My question: is Bj running jobs in parallel or one after another?

Thank you,
Damir

Answer (score 0):

BackgroundJob will only allow one worker to run per webserver instance.  This is by design to keep things simple.  Here is a quote from Bj's README:

> If one ignores platform specific details the design of Bj is quite simple: the
>   main Rails application submits jobs to table, stored in the database.  The act
>   of submitting triggers exactly one of two things to occur:
>
> 1) a new long running background runner to be started
>
> 2) an existing background runner to be signaled
>
> The background runner refuses to run two copies of itself for a given
>   hostname/rails_env combination.  For example you may only have one background
>   runner processing jobs on localhost in development mode.
>
> The background runner, under normal circumstances, is managed by Bj itself -
>   you need do nothing to start, monitor, or stop it - it just works.  However,
>   some people will prefer manage their own background process, see 'External
>   Runner' section below for more on this.
>
> The runner simply processes each job in a highest priority oldest-in fashion,
>   capturing stdout, stderr, exit_status, etc. and storing the information back
>   into the database while logging it's actions.  When there are no jobs to run
>   the runner goes to sleep for 42 seconds; however this sleep is interuptable,
>   such as when the runner is signaled that a new job has been submitted so,
>   under normal circumstances there will be zero lag between job submission and
>   job running for an empty queue.

You can learn more on the github page: [Here](http://github.com/ahoward/bj)